# Input values in table from external file and increment rows accordingly

Tags: tables, longtable, external-files

I am trying to create a report in table format and values in table have to input from some external file (or excel file). Can this be achieved in Latex?
If yes, then the number of table rows should be auto increment according to input data. I tried using `\longtable`but could not succeed. 
following is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.7 in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, graphicx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{30pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{lll}
          %  \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=30pt]{logo.jpg}} &          \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Variable Messsage Sign Report}}  \\
                             & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Downloaded by USER on DATE and TIME}  
\end{tabular}\\}
\cfoot{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{hcc.jpg}
\vspace{-100 px}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-400 px}
\begin{table}[]
\textbf{Variable Message Sign Summary} \\
\centering
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][4in][t]{\textwidth}
\centering
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{longtable}[100pt]    {|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline 
\textbf{Status} & \textbf{SCN} & \textbf{Slide} & \textbf{Message\_Text} &     \textbf{Time} & \textbf{Created\_by} & \textbf{Created\_on} &     \textbf{Updated\_on} & \textbf{Deleted\_on} \\ \hline
 &sdfgdfsgdfsg dfg dfgdfgdfg d &  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 &gfdgdfgdf  fgdfgdf sdfgg   &  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 &  dfgfdg dfgdfg dffgdfg &  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 &  dfgdfgd dfgdfg dfgdfg&  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 & fgdfg dffgdfgdf dffgdf  &  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 &  dfgdfgd dfgdfg dfgdfg&  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 & fgdfg dffgdfgdf dffgdf  &  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 & fgdfg dffgdfgdf dffgdf  &  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 &gfdgdfgdf  fgdfgdf sdfgg   &  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 &  dfgfdg dfgdfg dffgdfg &  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 &  dfgdfgd dfgdfg dfgdfg&  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
 & fgdfg dffgdfgdf dffgdf  &  &  &  &  &  &  &    \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\egroup
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

PS: pardon for using some packages which are not useful here

Attached is the screenshot of what I am getting as an output.[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. If you know that some packages are not useful/relevant, why not just remove them from the example?  And by the way, the whole point of a `longtable` is that it can break across pages, when you put it inside a `minipage` page breaks are no longer possible.

Comment: Use e.g. the `csvsimple` package. Then you can convert a csv file to a tabular with a single command.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. So I removed minipage now, but still the rows are mixing up with the footer and no page break is generated.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that you have a `table` environment as well. That also needs to go. And you probably want to remove the negative vspaces.